# Printing a character of a file given its positon and line number

Tags: python

I am not a very experienced programmer, new to Python and stuck using an old versio (2.5.2). I've got a problem that I'm going to have to break down into fundamental, basic steps.  As an examplt, I need to figure out how to print the 4 th character of the 10th line of an input file.

I must use a "for in line enumerate" to maintain functionality with other sections of the script.  I need something that is compatable with a "for in line enumerate" and can live after it's placement in the code.  Every idea I've tried gives the error:  "mixing iteration and read methods would lose data".

I think if I start by just printing a character given by its positon on a given line of an input file, I can take it from there.  Thanks.

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include your attempt at solving the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `readlines()` to read the file and store each line in a list (let us call that list 
'lines').
Then the ith element of jth line will simply be `lines[j][i]`

Example:

```
f = open('sample.txt', 'r')
lines = f.readlines()
print lines[10][4]  # Prints 4th character of the 10th line
```

Can you take it from here?

Comment: That is giving the error: "mixing iteration and read methods would lose data".

Comment: Are you using that inside a for loop? It's not meant to be. Don't use any loops. Simple call `f.readlines` and inspect what's in there.

Comment: It is inside a loop, after a "for in line enumerate".  If I had to change this much the greater part of the script would have to be rewritten as far as I can tell.

Comment: See! You're calling f.readlines() inside the loop every time it runs. Call it before you start the loop, and then use `for nr, line in enumerate(lines):`

Comment: I will try to implement that.  Thanks, first time I've heard about this issue.

Comment: slider this is getting me somewhere, but I may have a fatal problem. I ultimatley need to print from lines[10:4] to the /eof marker, which seems to imply the need for a loop. At least your idea, and how to implemt it, has given me something to experiment with.

Comment: slider this is getting me somewhere, but I may have a fatal problem. I ultimatley need to print from lines[10:4] to the /eof marker, which seems to imply the need for a loop. At least your idea, and how to implemt it, has given me something to experiment with. – user2994541 16 mins ago